# How do I remove a car window sticker?

Tags: cleaning, car, glass, adhesive, vehicle

We recently bought a new - used - vehicle that has two window stickers on it. I want to remove both of them, however the one that I particularly want to remove is very firmly stuck.

I tried to remove it with my finger nail first; however, very little of the sticker came off and the texture of my fingernail against the window was rather unbearable.

I'm not sure what to use on the window to remove it and am concerned that any chemicals would damage it because it is tinted. Peeling it off with my fingers is also incredibly ineffective.

Is there another good way to remove the stickers from the window?

Comment: You may like to have a look at [Remove a sticker from glass](http://m.wikihow.com/Remove-a-Sticker-from-Glass/)

Comment: First apply a wet sponge to it for 10-20 minutes. Then re-attempt removal, scraping, etc, but not too hard. If it gets tricky get some acetone from the chemist, that will shift it. Apply with care, do not inhale etc. It is nail-polish remover.

Answer (score 8):

For starters try using your hair blower to add heat to the sticker, and see if that doesn't help pulling it off.

Next step would be to use a scraper of some sort, i.e. [oven scraper or paint scraper](https://www.google.no/search?q=oven++or+paint+scraper&tbm=isch), and use this gently. You should be able to use these without damaging the car window. If you feel uncertain, you could opt for a plastic scraper.

In the end you'll most likely need to use adhesive remover, acetone, WD-40 or similar to remove the remaining sticker residue. But firstly try with just hot water and (dish washer) soap.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest method  I would opt is soap water.

1) Take some soap water in a [sprayer](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=sprayer&client=ubuntu&hs=oXi&channel=fs&biw=1535&bih=805&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi47_TJz9rJAhVFA44KHZLxAGEQ_AUIBigB#channel=fs&tbm=isch&q=water+sprayer).

2) With your finger nails , try to pull out sticker slowly.If you find your fingers being hurt, you could also use [paper knife](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=sprayer&client=ubuntu&hs=oXi&channel=fs&biw=1535&bih=805&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi47_TJz9rJAhVFA44KHZLxAGEQ_AUIBigB#channel=fs&tbm=isch&q=paper+pen+knife) instead.If you find that this sticker is going to tear, apply some soap water on its adhesive side and wait.

Now do step 2 with patience until you get the entire sticker gone.Now there is a chance for glass to be filled with stickers glue.You can clean this by using salt and paper.

1) Take some paper and salt in it.

2) Try to rub this salt contained paper so as to remove the sticker left overs. You can see them, being removed.

3) Do the step 2 to complete the left overs on your glass .

Answer (score 2):

If the sticker is on top of tint (it's on the inside of the car), you'll probably have to remove the entire tint and have it retinted if you wanted. If it's on the outside it would be sitting on glass alone. You can heat it with a blow dryer and it should peel off. Wipe the sticker glue residue off with a rag and some gasoline. I took the dealer sticker off my car this way.

Rinse your vehicle and hands off after. Gasoline isn't great for either.

Answer (score 2):

Apply WD-40 or goo-gone, wait 2 hours, and it should lift right up.  The key is to *wait* and let it soak in and work.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the blade from a boxcutter, wedge it under the sticker, and push.  Once the sticker is off use the blade in the same manner to remove the leftover adhesive.